Are these 2 Gates Carbon Rohloff CDX and CDX-EXP rear sprockets interchangeable?
My bicycle came with a Gates CDX-EXP rear sprocket. Online I can only find the CDX variant. And I was hoping to use the CDX variant.
Here images of the 2 parts and links to the manufacturers website.
https://shop.carbondrive.net/en/CDX-Rear-Sprocket-20T-Rohloff-Expedition/CDXR20ROSE-AM

https://shop.carbondrive.net/en/CDX-Rear-Sprocket-20T-Rohloff/CDXR20ROS-AM

Both are for Rohloff and both have 22 teeth. Both images have CDX-EXP written on the sprocket side. But there must be some differences because

CDX-EXP is US$10 more expensive. About $100 vs $110.
They have different numbers

CDXR20ROSE-AM / CT1120RSSB
CDXR20ROS-AM / CT1120RSMN



So my questions

Are these 2 parts interchangeable. If my bike currently has a CDX-EXP will the CDX fit?
In general, are CDX-EXP and CDX interchangeable. This answer seems to say that https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/65508/67012
Is the material different? e.g. CDX-EXP should last longer?

This site Gates Carbon Product Lines says CDX is stainless steel. CDX-EXP is not mentioned. Only CDX-black. I assume CDX-EXP is the new CDX-black (or the other way around)?


Any other differences that I should be aware of?

I did send a message to the manufacturer but they have not replied.

Seems to be an expedition version for Rohloff.  It’s unclear if you need a matching belt or whether you can mix and match with CDX https://www.cyclingabout.com/new-gates-cdxexp-expedition-carbon-belt-drivetrain/

It's possible the black one has wider teeth for a wider belt but they are functionally interchangeable and the standard CDX belt can be used with either: the tooth pitch and profile are the same. Check the beltline matches when changing parts.

I received a reply from the manufacturer's technical representative in Europe. (Universal Transmissions / Gates Carbon).
My questions to them are

I have a Rohloff Rear Sprocket CDX EXP 20T.
Can I replace that sprocket with a CDX 20T ? Are these 2 parts compatible? What is the difference between CDX and CDX-EXP?

Their answer

These 2 pulleys are compatible with each other.  The main difference is that
The CDX Black variant is made of chrome-moly steel, while the other variant is made of stainless steel.


